# Console statment not waiting for the function return in javascript

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, async.js, awaitility

I'm trying to initialize a variable `x` to the value returned by the `showData` function. Here's my code:

```
app.post("/view/show", (req,res) => {
    let x = showData(req.body.custmerName);
    console.log(x);
}
```

And here is the `showData` function:

```
const showData = (custName) => {
    const customer = mongoose.model(custName ,collectionSchema,custName);
    customer.find( (error,data) => {
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            return data;  
        }
    });
}
```

However, the console shows `undefined`. If I add `console.log(data)` to the `showData` function, I can see that I was able to successfully fetch data from the database.

I understand that `console.log(x)` is not waiting for the execution of `showData()`, due to the synchronous property of JavaScript. How can I get the value from the function and log it to the console, instead of getting `undefined`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Many, _many_ similar questions have been asked already. Search SO for "javascript async undefined" and you'll be able to find your answer. Here's one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async/await or callback when dealing with the async functions.

```js
app.post("/view/show", (req,res) => {
  showData(req.body.custmerName, (err, res) => {
    const x = res;
    console.log(x);
  });
});

const showData = (custName, callback) => {
  const customer = mongoose.model(custName ,collectionSchema,custName);
  customer.find(callback);
}
```

Comment: @VELDASRDURAI if this answer solved your problem, it would be good if you accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used Mongoose before, but looking at the docs, there doesn't seem to be a version of the find function that just takes a callback function.

Try passing the query object also (in your case, an empty object should suffice):

```
customer.find({}, (error,data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        return data;  
    }
});
```

From the docs:

```
// find all documents
await MyModel.find({});

// find all documents named john and at least 18
await MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 } }).exec();

// executes, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});

// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();

// passing options
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }).exec();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need an asynchronous function to do that. Do the following:

```
app.post("/view/show", async(req,res) => {
    let x = await showData(req.body.custmerName);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: This will not work - `showData` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: In order to async.await to work, the async function should return promise.